# Cannot find any of the supported PHP image extensions

Tags: php, tomcat, ckeditor, kcfinder

I am trying to run kcfinder with ckeditor and i am getting the message
Cannot find any of the supported PHP image extensions!
What is reason ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably looking for [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) and/or [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) extensions. Clearly you have neither installed.

The reason they're not installed will depend on who hosts your PHP environment. It seems likely that shared hosting providers may not have them enabled.

Comment: Yes, I am running PHP along with Java Application, on tomcat. How to fix it.

Comment: The two links I gave you include installation instructions. Personally, I use GD.